# mingw reports errors when assembling code

Tags: assembly, mingw, intel, directive

I try to assemble this code:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK
.DATA
    op1 dw 10
    op2 dw 5
    result dw ?
.CODE
.STARTUP
    mov ax, op1
    add ax, op2
    mov result, ax
    mov al, result
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
.EXIT
END
```

with this mingw command:
      as example.asm

and it reports me these errors:

```
a.asm: Assembler messages:
a.asm: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
a.asm:1: Error: no such instruction: `section .MODEL small'
a.asm:2: Error: no such instruction: `section .STACK'
a.asm:3: Error: no such instruction: `section .DATA'
a.asm:4: Error: no such instruction: `op1 dw 10'
a.asm:5: Error: no such instruction: `op2 dw 5'
a.asm:6: Error: no such instruction: `result dw?'
a.asm:7: Error: no such instruction: `section .CODE'
a.asm:8: Error: no such instruction: `section .STARTUP'
a.asm:9: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
a.asm:10: Error: too many memory references for `add'
a.asm:11: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
a.asm:12: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
a.asm:13: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
a.asm:14: Error: junk `h' after expression
a.asm:14: Error: operand size mismatch for `int'
a.asm:15: Error: no such instruction: `section .EXIT'
a.asm:16: Error: no such instruction: `section END'
```

I learned to program in this way and I don't understand why it doesn't work... what's the solution?

Comment: Each assembler has its own syntax and your code is not for the mingw assembler (which is GNU `as`). Judging from the directives, your code is for `MASM`. Also note that it is DOS code, which mingw is again unsuitable for.

Comment: tasm report me that it is incompatible with 64 bit version windows

Comment: Then run TASM in DOSBox.

Comment: Rather than tasm why not use nasm?

Comment: Even if you could compile this code, not sure what you intended it to do. `int 21h` with ah = 2 would write a single character in `dl` to the console. Your code doesn't load a character into `dl` .

Comment: Older versions of masm(6.15) with a linker that works with 16 bit code can be found here: http://www2.hawaii.edu/~pager/312/masm%20615%20downloading.htm  . The exectuables are in the bin directory. Besides my comment about int 21h/ah=2 above your code has one other issue `mov al, result` should be `mov al, byte ptr [result]` since you defined `result` as a 2 byte word and are trying to move it inton 8 bit register (`al`)